# Anaconda cannot import scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

Importing scipy in iPython gave me:

```
In [1]: import scipy
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4dc45f4c0083> in <module>()

----> 1 import scipy

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py in <module>()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py in <module>()

ImportError: cannot import name _ccallback_c

In [2]:
```

Did a complete update of all the files of Anaconda

```
> conda update --all
```

and the error remains. Did a complete search on the web and there are similar problems but without solutions. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am giving you two solutions which might work by my expereince

*1. create a virtualenv and install the scipy package in that virtualenv and give path like this*

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/shashi/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import scipy
```

*2.
 Download the source code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/archive/v0.18.0-1.zipand unpack it. Open a command window in the folder where the setup.py of the module is located and type*

```
scipy python setup.py install
```

Comment: Solved, thank you! The package is good, just had to add the folder site-packages to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like scipy is not installed

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy
```

Try this and let us know if you receive the error again

Cheers!

Comment: Solved, thank you! Just had to set PYTHONPATH environment variable to site-packages folder. Anaconda does not initializes this variable.

Comment: As mentioned, the best is to install scipy using conda. One thing thoug: If youre missing anaconda, youre probably missing a bunch of packages that are almost standard... So you might want to do `conda install anaconda` to install them all...